# Exploring Puppet filebuckets: Error: Could not run: File not found

Tags: backup, puppet

I am exploring Puppet filebuckets with a manifest that contains the following excerpt:

```
file { '/tmp/test' :
  backup,
  # ...
}
```

When I apply this manifest, Puppet reports that it backed up the old version of `/tmp/test` into the (local) filebucket `puppet`:

```
Info: /Stage[main]/<module>/File[/tmp/test]:
Filebucketed /tmp/test to puppet with sum <hash>
```

This matches the following description in the [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/types/file.html#file-attribute-backup):

> Default value: puppet, which backs up to a filebucket of the same
>   name. (Puppet automatically creates a local filebucket named puppet if
>   one doesn’t already exist.)

When I now try to inspect the contents of the filebucket with `puppet filebucket --local list` (or `puppet filebucket --local --bucket puppet list`) I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not run: File not found
```

What can explain this behavior and how can I successfully inspect the contents of the (local) filebucket? This is for Puppet version 4.10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to a [bug](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5206) in Puppet 4. This workaround applies:

```
puppet filebucket --local \
  --bucket /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/clientbucket \
  list
```

**UPDATE** Pipeing the output from this command into `sort -k 2` will sort entries by date (newest first).